# Is it valid statement that 3.x extension use only 1 function per controller?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

```
Because Lendr is a Joomla! 3.x extension our controllers are 
single function controllers, meaning     they all contain only one function (execute).
```

Is it valid statement that 3.x extension use only 1 function per controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having recently used the Lendr example as the foundation of a component, I share your question.  I can't find any other examples where the controllers have only execute functions.  Lendr is rather light on the backend and having to develop any additional features leads one to use "legacy" controllers.  One would think that com_content or com_users in the backend would be really state of the art.  They are all legacy.

Comment: As always, patches are welcome!  Really that's how it goes, people do the work and code gets done. Something like com_content or com_users is a major major job impacting millions of websites.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid to say that in new MVC extensions there is one task per controller but the tasks can be complex tasks.   You can see this currently in master in com_config and also in my repo in my com_cache/com_checkin refactoring.
https://github.com/elinw/joomla-cms/tree/checkin-cache/administrator/components/com_cache
Also of course take a look at the installation application whcih is probably deleted from your repository but you can pull down from github or get from the zip file.